# Power BI Transpose Report data

Tags: report, powerbi

I have this data in excel that I imported into Power BI

```
Area    Attach  Pay Start   Entry
North    1       0   1       0
North    1       0   1       0
North    1       0   1       1
North    0       1   1       0
West     1       0   1       0
West     1       0   1       1
West     0       0   1       0
West     1       1   1       0
West     1       0   1       0
West     1       0   1       0
West     1       0   1       1
```

I produced a report using matrix and sum the values of Attach, Pay, Start   and Entry then group by Area

My current output

[image]

My Desired Output

[image]

i can do the formatting dont worry about it

Comment: i recommend you to do in in query designer before you do it in powerBi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a show on row option in formatting pane:

[image]